# How to turn Javascript String to Object Reference

Tags: javascript, object

The problem I am having is turning a String to an object reference. If I want to reference the answers object.

However, I have a string that references the letters in the answers object.

```js
var objPosition = {
  "question": "In Stuart times what punishment was given to wives who talked too much?",
  "answers": {
    "A": "Thumbs were squeezed in a vice",
    "B": "Had to walk round in a barrel",
    "C": "Wore an iron mask with a spike in the mouth"
  },
  "answer": "C",
  "explanation": "N/A",
  "type": "Stuart"
};

var a = "a";
console.log(objPosition.answers.a);
```

However I constantly get the undefined error, I am wanting to convert my String back into an object reference?

Comment: Use bracket notation? `objPosition.answers[a]`

Comment: Note: Object properties are case sensitive. `objPosition.answers.A` will work. If you want to use the `a` variable then you need to use the bracket notion `(objPosition.answers[a]` and set the variable to a capital `A`.

Comment: You want to have `var a = "A";`, not `var a = "a";` -- once you fix that, you can do what @evolutionxbox suggested

Comment: javascript is case sensitive. use `objPosition.answers.A` instead

Comment: If your question is not yet resolved, please add some more context to your code